# Swing analysis of a cricketing shot

Tags: discrete-mathematics

A reference swing motion of a cricketing shot is captured, in 3D space. Players are asked to emulate the same, in synchronous with reference swing motion.

Have to analyze how close the player's swing motion is with respect to reference swing motion.

Each player's hand (that holds the bat) length differ from one another. Hence player's 3D motion has to be normalized before being compared with reference motion.

Any directions on how to approach the above problem?. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @user1001001. Each player's hand length (that holds the bat) differ from one another. Hence player's 3D motion has to be normalized before being compared with reference motion.  How to go about normalizing player's 3D motion?. Have edited the question to include this detail. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pick in advance the parameters to normalize, which are not functions of the correctness of the swing. Things like where the batter is standing, their height (spatial translation, rotation and scaling), when time starts and possibly the speed of the swing (time translation and scaling). Then we have a nonlinear optimization problem to fit the user swing to the target swing as closely as possible by tuning these parameters. Specifically, pick reference points on the bat and associated sample times to fit the trial swings to (you can choose these more densely for more important parts of the swing and sparsely otherwise). Define a function of the tunable parameters and of a trial swing that gives the modified trial swing by the parameters. Solve the resulting nonlinear least squares problem of fitting the trial swing to the reference swing at the picked reference points. You can at this point read off the l2 distance if you want some measure of distance between the swings. If you find that irrelevant details of the swing are being measured here, you can try to account by adding more tunable parameters or tweaking the fitting points.